# Is there anyway to clean this SQL/JS up?

Tags: javascript, sql

I am working on a bot that sends users riddles when the join a discord server, the code below selects a random riddle from one table, saves it in another table with the user's (who the riddle has been sent to) id, before sending them a message with the riddle in.

Does anyone know if there is a better way to do this than what I have done, because it feels a bit ugly/inefficent having a query in a query.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  connection.query('SELECT riddle FROM riddles AS riddle ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1', function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;

    connection.query('INSERT INTO cache VALUES (?, ?)', [member.id, results[0].riddle], function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
    });

    member.send(results[0].riddle);
  });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: This may be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, that's a pretty good way to go about it. Though you probably want to send the riddle only after you've ensured it's been saved to the database.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. Do you know the best way to catch those errors? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with them (and how the Discord client is built). You could just log them in the console, for instance.